# Configuring Epson Stylus NX420 Scanner on Debian Wheezy

Tags: usb, scanner, printer, sane

I'm trying to get my Epson Stylus NX420 printer/scanner combo to work with sane on Debian Wheezy (via USB). I've got cups and saned running, and I've added the printer in the cups configuration page. The printer itself works fine, but I cannot get xsane or simple-scan to recognize the scanner. x-sane says "No devices available." and simple-scan gives an error message at startup saying "No scanners detected. Please check your scanner is connected and powered on."

Here is some information that might be of use:

- My user is in the scanner, lpadmin, and plugdev groups
- I currently have the printer set to use the Epson ESC/P-R driver (although it is my understanding that the CUPS printer driver should have no effect on the scanner).
- I have tried using epson and epson2 in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf with no
  luck

I have included the following in /etc/sane.d/epson.conf:

```
usb 0x04b8 0x0864
usb /dev/usbscanner0
usb /dev/usb/scanner0
```

Running sane-find-scanner (whether as root or a regular user), gives the following output:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8, product=0x0864) at libusb:002:004
```

Running scanimage -L as root gives me:

```
device `epson:libusb:003:003' is a Epson PID flatbed scanner
```

However, running scanimage -L as the regular user (who is in the groups listed above) gives:

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate) ...
```

Given the information above, can anyone suggest other things I might try to get this working?

Comment: FYI: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181547/crunchbang-cant-use-simple-scan-without-administrator-rights

Answer (score 0):

Does installing the libre portion of EpsonScan and using the `--list` flag turn up anything? http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/epsonscan2_e.html#sec10-4