# Crunchbang: Can't use simple-scan without administrator rights

Tags: permissions, scanner

I'm running the latest version of Crunchbang 64-bit on a Dell E5510 notebook.

Installing my printer and scanner worked fine - I just used an existing Ubuntu tutorial. However, scanning without starting Simple-Scan as `sudo` produces an error message. My main account is listed as part of the group `scanner`, according to the output of `less /etc/group`. To my limited knowledge, this should suffice, shouldn't it? What more steps are necessary in order to run simple-scan without `sudo`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found similar question asked on [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/298298/scanning-only-works-under-sudo-ubuntu). Also this Ubuntu [how-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo#Permission_Issues) could be useful. And there's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/229343) regarding permissions to access a scaner.

Summarizing this sources:

- Add saned to the group which owns your scanner device: `sudo adduser saned scanner`. Note that device may be owned by different group, so use `sane-find-scanner` to determine the device and `ls -al /dev/bus/usb/XXX/XXX` to identify the group. Then add saned to this group.

There's not very secure way to run saned as root.

- Add this line to `/etc/rc.local` (before exit 0): `chmod -R a+w /dev/bus/usb`
- Edit/create the following file: `/etc/xinetd.d/saned`:

`service saned 
{
socket_type = stream
server = /usr/sbin/saned
protocol = tcp
user = root
group = root
wait = no
disable = no
}`

- Edit `/etc/default/saned`:
  `RUN_AS_USER=root`
  and 
  `RUN=yes`
- Reboot.

Comment: I tried your first advice and got `abc@crunchbang:~$ ls -al /dev/bus/usb/002/004
crw-rw-r-T 1 root lp 189, 131 Jan 28 17:09 /dev/bus/usb/002/004` as a result. Sorry for the dumb question, but what exactly is the group here?

Comment: Group is `lp` here. To add saned to lp group run `sudo adduser saned lp`.

Comment: After following all steps the scanner works as it should. Could you, in simple terms, explain what was done here exactly?

Comment: Service saned which works with scanner is started by inetd with user name "saned". To have access to it first you tried to add saned to be in the 'lp' group (which your device belongs to). But that didn't help because it seems that saned nor lp nor any other person has access to the device other than "root". By going through last steps you just tell xinetd to run saned as root. This 'bug' is a direct result from bug that sane does not have udev rules in place to give the device proper permissions when plugged in, resulting in the root:root ownership.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However, I was a bit too quick to say that everything worked properly - because it didn't the next time I rebooted the system. Thus, I checked all instructions once more and edited `/etc/default/saned`: `RUN=yes`. Now the problems seems resolved for good.

Comment: Right, added to answer.

Comment: I don't know why, but the bug recurs every now and then. Any more ideas, kirill-a? Or anybody else?

Comment: After reading up on the bug, the problem seems to be missing udev rules: [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/188552).

Comment: @T.K. Yeah, I mentioned that above. BTW, check this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sane#Permission_problem), it describes how to fix your udev rules.

Comment: Thank you, I must have overlooked it the first time. Still, despite all the ArchWiki steps, nothing has changed. What struck me as funny was that there was no `49-sane.rules` file when I tried to edit it. Any idea why?